# How Do I return Data from a Table if the user id Matches the Current User

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, users (which contains user_id & user info) and homeloans (which contains user_id and loan info) I am trying to return the loan info that matches the current user's id. Currently the system is just returning all loan info from multiple users.

```
SELECT loan_id, amount, term, requestedrate, address FROM homeloans
```

I believe adding a WHERE would solve this issue but I'm not sure how to compare it to the user_id from users.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `WHERE` condition which would be something like:

```sql
SELECT loan_id, amount, term, requestedrate, address FROM homeloans WHERE user_id = '1';
```

instead of `'1'`, you pass the user's id.